# ios package ipa works well with Debug ,but with release some error appeared

Tags: ios, ipad, debugging, release

This is my app in Appstore, https://itunes.apple.com/cn/app/beijing-zoo/id651363736?mt=8
it's a map guide for Beijing Zoo of China.
now ,the problem is that if i build and run with "Commond + R " ,the app works fine in my iPad,
but ,when using the menu " Product - > Archive ->Distribute-> Submit to the iOS App Store  /  Save for Enterprise or Ad-Hoc Deployment  / Exports as XCode Archives " package the .app file to ipa , install it to my iPad by the iTunes,problem appears, the "Button "on the Map can not be tapped...  no response..   someone tell me how to solve this>?? is't a bug of Apple or not?  tks~~!

Comment: No, it's not an Apple bug, it's a bug in your code.

Comment: You need to test your application with release build settings as well.  Don't ask how, there are plenty of resources out there that will help you out with that.

Answer (score 0):

Check to see if you are signing the AdHoc version with the correct provisioning profile. Also, connect your iPad and goto Organizer -> Devices, select your device and check the Console Logs to see if there is any error.

Comment: If it's improperly signed then surely the entire app won't run?